# How to print only instant members of ann object in php

Tags: php

I want to print/rcho instant members of an object with no recursion. print_r() prints members recursively. Do you know of any function for this?

Comment: For debugging purposes? Then I'd install xdebug (which you should have anyway) and set its recursion limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to echo out properties of an object as long as they aren't  another object or an array.

This can be done with [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php).

```
class A
{
    public $test1;

    protected $test2;

    private $test3;

    public $test4;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test1 = 1;
        $this->test2 = 2;
        $this->test3 = 3;

        $this->test4 = new stdClass();
        $this->test4->prop1 = 1;
        $this->test4->prop2 = 2;

    }
}

$obj = new A();

// our control - what you have at the moment:
print_r($obj);
```

Results in the following output:

```
A Object
(
    [test1] => 1
    [test2:protected] => 2
    [test3:A:private] => 3
    [test4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [prop1] => 1
            [prop2] => 2
        )

)
```

The following, using reflection:

```
$refl = new ReflectionObject($obj);
$properties = $refl->getProperties();

foreach ($properties as $property) {
    // ensure we can also access protected and private properties
    $property->setAccessible(true);

    $value = $property->getValue($obj);

    if (!is_object($value) && !is_array($value)) {
        echo $property->getName() . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
test1: 1
test2: 2
test3: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [`instanceof`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) then ?

```
  <?php
    class A
    {
    }

    $obj = new A();

    if ($obj instanceof A) {
       echo 'Yes I am !';
    }
    if ($obj1 instanceof A) {

    }
    else
    {
       echo "No am not !";
    }
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Yes I am !
No am not !
```